# Chrome Doesn't Render Until I Move The Cursor

Tags: graphics, google-chrome

I've run into this issue in the past, and it's always been insidious and frustrating. It just popped up on my machine either last night or in the past few days. Randomly, when I opened a new page in Chrome, it won't render until I move the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same issue with Juno on Intel Kabylake CPU with Intel HD 620.

I had to disable GPU acceleration in settings. If that doesn't help try one more step - go to “chrome://flags” and disable “GPU Rasterization”.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try turning off the GPU acceleration first and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The issue hasn't popped up since disabling GPU acceleration, so looks like that did it. Thanks again!